# Text Classification, How to convert text strings to vector representation

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, svm, text-classification

I am working on a text classification program. My training data is 700+ text categories and each categories contains 1-350 text phrases. 16k+ phrases total. The data that needs to be classified are text phrases. I want to classify the data so it gives me 5 most similar categories. The training data shares a lot of common words.

My first attempt was using Naive Bayes Theorem using this library on github because this library was very easy to use and allowed me to load my training data as strings. But other users reported issues and when I tried to classify my data, my input is either classified wrong or not classified.

https://github.com/ptnplanet/Java-Naive-Bayes-Classifier

So I think the library was the issue, so Im going try different libraries and look into k means clustering since my data is high variance.

So when I looking at other libraries, they all require input and training data as a vector matrix. I looked at word2vec and td-idf to convert text vectors. I understand tf-idf, and that I can get the weight of the word compared to the rest of the documents. But how can I use it classify my input data to categories? Would each category be a document? Or would all categories be a single document?

edit:data sample

SEE_BILL-see bill

SEE_BILL-bill balance

SEE_BILL-wheres my bill

SEE_BILL-cant find bill

PAY_BILL-pay bill

PAY_BILL-make payment

PAY_BILL-lower balance

PAY_BILL-remove balance

PAST_BILL-last bill

PAST_BILL-previous bill

PAST_BILL-historical bill

PAST_BILL-bill last year

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the end of your question doesn't make any sense because you didn't say what are the classes you want to to classify the text phrases to. Now, I can help you with the vectorization of the text phrases.

Tf-idf is pretty good but you have to have a good preprocessing to do it. Also, you would have to create the vectors yourself. The problem with it is that you will give the vector of length of all the distinct words in your dataset, even the same words in different forms in which they occur in the dataset. So if you have the word `go` in your dataset, it's likely that there will be several forms of that word including `going`, `Go`, `gone`, `went` and so on. That's why you have to have a good preprocessing tho put all of those forms of word `go` to it's root form. Also, you have to lowercase the whole dataset because words `go` and `Go` are not the same. But even if you do all of that and make a perfect preprocessing pipeline, you will get the vector of length 20k+. You would then have to manually select the features (words) you want to leave in the vector and delete the others. That means, if you want to have vector of size 300 you would have to delete the 19 700 words from the vector. Of course, you would be left with the 300 best distinctive. If you want to dive into it deeper and see how exactly it works, you can check it out [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/tfidf-for-piece-of-text-in-python-43feccaa74f8)

On the other hand, word2vec maps any word to a 300 dimensional vector. Of course, you would have to do some preprocessing, similar to the tf-idf, but this method is much less sensitive. You can find how word2vec works [here](https://skymind.ai/wiki/word2vec)

In conclusion, I would recommend you go with word2vec because it's much easier to start with. There is pretrained model from Google which you can download [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I am trying classify text phrases to different categories similar to a chat bot. We already use an enterprise chat bot solution, but this will used to help training the bot. We will use past training data to match new user phrases to categorizes. I looked at deeplearnings4j's implementation of word2vec

Comment: We have around 700+ training categories and some the of categories have very similar training data to other categories. I looked at word2vec from deeplearning and other sites, and I have a general idea how it works. So would I build a word2vec for each category and then compare each new training phrase with the each model and then select the closest matches? I added some sample categories in the original post.

Comment: No, word2vec is already the model which turns words into sequence of numbers. What you want to do is: when you get the phrase, transform each word to a vector with word2vec model, somehow join the vectors to a single one (maybe try with adding the vectors from all the words in that phrase together) and put it in a clustering algorithm. It will build the cluster with vectors of all of the phrases and you will then select the closest one by the distance in the cluster. That would be my first try

Answer (score 0):

The two most popular approaches would be to:

- represent each phrase/sentence as a bag of words where you basically one-hot encode each word of the phrase and the dimension of the encoding is the dimension of your vocabulary (total number of words)
- use embeddings based on popular models, like `word2vec` which put each word in a X-dimensional vector space (e.g. 300-dimensional) so each of your phrases/sentences would be a sequence of X-dimensional vectors

An even more extreme approach would be to embed whole sentences using models like [universal-sentence-encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2). In short: it's similar to `word2vec` but instead of words converts whole sentences to (512-dimensional) vector space. Than it's easier to find "similar" sentences.

Comment: Are there universal-sentence-encoder libraries for Java? All I can find is python libraries